# Reading the Lines of CSV file using MQL5

Tags: file, csv, mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to read the last line time value from a csv file. Check the following:

```
2018-07-26 11:04:00 1.17272 1.17275 1.17267 1.17272
2018-07-26 11:05:00 1.17272 1.17273 1.17265 1.17268
2018-07-26 11:06:00 1.17268 1.17273 1.17261 1.17264
```

The above is sample data. I have tried the following code and the result is as follows:

```cpp
int file = FileOpen("latest.csv",FILE_READ|FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_CSV|FILE_COMMON);
   if(file != INVALID_HANDLE)
   {
      FileSeek(file,-100,SEEK_END);

      while(!FileIsLineEnding(file))
      {
         Print(FileReadString(file));
      }
   }

   FileClose(file);
```

Output:

```
8-07-26 11:06:00
1.17268
1.17273
1.17261
1.17264
```

I m not getting the complete date value. Even if I try to increase the offset of the `FileSeek()` function.

Kindly, let me know how is it possible to read the csv file's last line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know mql5 but here's what I think the problem is:

- The file is opened in csv mode (`FILE_CSV`), and it looks like `FileReadString()` reads a single field (not a full row) - just like `FileReadNumber()` reads a number from a column. So the function keeps reading separate fields until a newline is encountered (and the first field (`date`) is only read partial because of the offset).

From the [docs](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/files/filereadstring):

> When reading from a bin-file. the length of a string to read must be
>   specified. When reading from a txt-file the string length is not
>   required, and the string will be read from the current position to the
>   line feed character "\r\n". **When reading from a csv-file**, the string
>   length isn't required also, **the string will be read from the current
>   position till the nearest delimiter** or till the text string end
>   character.

So, instead of `FILE_CSV`, using `FILE_TXT` should read the whole line. Of course, you'll have to skip the first partial line (`pos -100`).

**To read the full last line**:

```cpp
int file = FileOpen("latest.csv",FILE_READ|FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_TXT|FILE_COMMON);

   if(file != INVALID_HANDLE)
   {
      FileSeek(file,-100,SEEK_END);

      // skip partial line
      FileReadString(file);

      // read last line
      Print(FileReadString(file));

      FileClose(file);
   }
```

**To only read the last date** you could still use CSV mode:

```cpp
int file = FileOpen("latest.csv",FILE_READ|FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_CSV|FILE_COMMON);

   if(file != INVALID_HANDLE)
   {
      FileSeek(file,-100,SEEK_END);

      // skip partial row
      while(!FileIsLineEnding(file))
      {
          FileReadString(file);
      }

      // read last date
      Print(FileReadString(file));
      // or maybe FileReadDatetime(file);

      FileClose(file);
   }
```

Also, [FileClose()](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/files/fileclose) should be inside the `if{} block`.